# AndEngine for Android 2.3

Tags: android, andengine

I'm making a android game for Gingerbread. When i tried downloading AndEngine from [official source](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine), it was only available for APK 15+ version.

The version in incompatible with Gingerbread. I even googled up looking for previous versions but couldn't find one. Help me out !

Answer (score 3):

Placing this in your manifest file will fix all your problems ^.^

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```